If $f(x)$ is a pdf that is symmetric about $a$ (AKA $f(a+x) = f(a-x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R})$ then $EX = a$.
I'm looking for help for the problem in the title. If $f(x)$ is a probability density function (so it's nonnegative and its integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is $1$) and is symmetric about $a$ (EDIT: and as pointed out in the comments, $EX$ must be finite) then $EX = a$.
I've been working on this problem a tiny bit here and there over the past few days but haven't gotten anywhere with it. I've tried integration by parts, using the linearity of expectation, and some other integration tricks to try to evaluate
$EX = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x)\,dx$
But none of the tricks seem to work. I'd appreciate some hints or help on this question.

Don't you need to assume $EX$ exists.

That's absolutely needed as an assumption but it wasn't included in the problem set where I got this from. Thanks for pointing it out.

I assume that $\mathbb E[|X|]<\infty$. Therefore:
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb E[X]=&\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\cdot x\; \text dx\\
    &=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\cdot (a+(x-a))\; \text dx\\
    &=\int_{\mathbb R}a\cdot f(x)\; \text dx+\int_{\mathbb R}(x-a)\cdot f(x)\; \text dx\\
    &=\mathbb E[a]+{\int_{\mathbb R}(x-a)\cdot f(x)\; dx}\\
    &=a+{\int_{\mathbb R^+}x\cdot f(x+a)\; \text dx}+{\int_{\mathbb R^-}x \cdot f(x+a)\; \text dx}&(\text{by substitution})\\
    &=a+\int_{\mathbb R^+}x\cdot f(x+a)\; \text dx-\int_{\mathbb R^+}x\cdot f(a-x)\; \text dx\\
    &=a+\int_{\mathbb R^+}x\cdot f(x+a)\; \text dx-\int_{\mathbb R^+}x\cdot f(a+x)\; \text dx&(\text{by symmetry})\\
    &=a.
\end{align*}

Let $Y= X-a$. Note that the assumption $f(a+x)= f(a-x)$ implies that $Y$ is equal in distribution to $-Y$ i.e. $Y\overset{d}{=} -Y$.
Indeed  the change of variables formula for densities implies that the density of $Y$ is given by
$$
f_{Y}(y) = f_{X}(a+y)\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|=f_{X}(a+y)
$$
while the density of $-Y$ is given by
$$
f_{-Y}(y) =f_{Y}(-y)=f_{X}(a-y)
$$
so that $Y$ and $-Y$ have the same density. Since $Y\overset{d}{=} -Y$,
$$
EY=-EY\implies EY =0 \implies EX =a.
$$
